# Error while github.exe opens "libcef.dll is either designated to run on Windows or it contains an error"

Tags: windows, github

Everything was fine but recently whenever I try to open `github.exe`, the following error message is shown to to me:

> libcef.dll is either designated to run on Windows or it contains an error
>
> [image]

I can't do anything. My PC is an HP G62 notebook with 64-bit Windows

Answer (score 0):

Bad image means you use a DLL with the wrong CPU architecture (32Bit DLL with a 64Bit or 64Bit DLL with a 32Bit Applications).

Get the correct DLL from here:

http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/